# Using Apache Rewrite Rule to pass information from URL to Filename

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been banging my head against this one and have unfortunately failed.  I'm hoping somebody can help me.

I'd like to pass information from a URL to a filename.  Basically I'd like to do the following:

There is only one real file on the server:
http://www.domain.com/download/file.zip

If a user enters the following URL into his browser:
http://www.domain.com/download/file_xyx.zip I'd like apache internally serving file.zip but the user downloading the file as file_xyz.zip

xyz is intended to be a variable (of any length) so the rewrite rule should simply accept anything it's place and always internally link to the same file.

I'm thinking this can be achieved with a rewrite rule, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?download/file_[0-9]+\.zip /download/file.zip [L]
```

If you are using htaccess files, you can place this rule in an htaccess file in the "download" folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /download/
RewriteRule ^file_[0-9]+\.zip file.zip [L]
```